# MySQL-Get latest data of 1st 4 days of current month

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have a table in my database which stores the `meters` energy value of 1st of every month. In case meter is offline it will store the value of the next day.

Below is my case

I have a record of a meter of past 2 months `February` and `March`. The `February` data is of `2019-02-01 00:00:00` but there are 4 rows for the month `March`. See the below image

[image]

In the above image the `1st,2nd and 3rd` of March have a null value of `FA` but the 4th March contains some value.

**What I have done?**

I am able to select the rows having values of `FA`.

**What I want to do?**

1. I want to get only the current month data i.e. Current month is `March` so it should get only march record and then next month it should get only `April` record and so on.
2. The query should not exceed the days limit more than 4 i.e. It should only check record for 1st four days of every month.

Here is my [DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8mXgXe3AS2jL1dMs8T7E7C/0)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to solve this is 
FOR 
I want to get only the current month data i.e. Current month is March so it should get only march record and then next month it should get only April record and so on.

```
means month(TV)= month(now())
```

and 
The query should not exceed the days limit more than 4 i.e. It should only check record for 1st four days of every month. `means day(TV)<= 4`

and finally your query

```
select * from `biz_pub_data_f_energy_m` a
 where a.`DATA_ID` = '1b9716122dd5408691a063227316ac0a'
 and a.`FA` is NOT NULL and month(TV)= month(now())
 and day(TV)<= 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c255699b135ced4979a3d1b1d04a040)**

```
select * from `biz_pub_data_f_energy_m` a
where a.`DATA_ID` = '1b9716122dd5408691a063227316ac0a'
and a.`FA` is NOT NULL and tv>=date(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(now())-1 DAY))
and tv<=DATE_ADD(date(DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(now())-1 DAY)), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```